# How to get a value of current index by escape any element using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select a value of current index from html using Jquery as below code.
**Issue** I can get my current index value but I want to escape all the value in **tag a** mean that I want to select only text of **Span**.

Here is HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <div class="data">
   <ul id="vurl">
      <li><a class="vdurl">Some Video</a><span class="url" style="display: none;">PRP_CMiFEYQ</span></li>
      <li><a class="vdurl">Some Video</a><span class="url" style="display: none;">PRP_CMiFEYQ</span></li>
      <li><a class="vdurl">Some Video</a><span class="url" style="display: none;">PRP_CMiFEYQ</span></li>
      <li><a class="vdurl">Some Video</a><span class="url" style="display: none;">PRP_CMiFEYQ</span></li>
      <li><a class="vdurl">Some Video</a> <span class="url" style="display: none;">PRP_CMiFEYQ </span> </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Here is Jquery.

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('ul#vurl li').on('click', function () {
        alert($(this).parent().text());
        console.log($('li.vdurl span.url').parent().text());
    });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('ul#vurl li').on('click', function () {

        console.log( $(this).children('span').text() );

    });

});
```

This way on click you will get the text of the `SPAN` element contained in clicked `LI` element

Comment: @RayonDabre span is hiding, not li.

Comment: @Gurami Dagundaridze
My god it is working thanks too much

Comment: `children()` seems faster than `find()`!

Comment: Which one is better between children and find method?

Comment: **find()** – search through the matched elements’ child, grandchild, great-grandchild…any levels down.
**children()** – search through the matched elements’ child only (single level down).

Comment: @Rayon Dabre,
That right thanks So the best answer is Children

Comment: Yes children is more performant in this case. If you are unsure whether span will be the direct child in the future than it is better to  use `.find( '.url' )` if you are unsure whether it will be `SPAN` tag then `.find( 'span.url' )`, the latter is least performant

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find` to find the span within the li tag and get its text :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul#vurl li').on('click', function() {
    //alert($(this).parent().text());
    alert($(this).find('span').text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <div class="data">
   <ul id="vurl">
      <li><a class="vdurl">Some Video1</a><span class="url" style="display: none;">PRP_CMiFEYQ1</span></li>
      <li><a class="vdurl">Some Video2</a><span class="url" style="display: none;">PRP_CMiFEYQ2</span></li>
      <li><a class="vdurl">Some Video3</a><span class="url" style="display: none;">PRP_CMiFEYQ3</span></li>
      <li><a class="vdurl">Some Video4</a><span class="url" style="display: none;">PRP_CMiFEYQ4</span></li>
      <li><a class="vdurl">Some Video5</a> <span class="url" style="display: none;">PRP_CMiFEYQ5 </span> </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`.find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)** to and its good to be more specific on `elements`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul#vurl li').on('click', function () {
        console.log( $(this).find('span.url').text() );
    });
});
```